# Missing panel icons at top right in GNOME3

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, gnome

I've got the problem with missing top right icons after the recent update of the system. 
I've found in one of the posts on ubuntugenius website the following sets of commands, but they did not help:

```
gconftool-2 --shutdown
gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/panel (This wipes the panel’s settings.)
rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel (This deletes the panel’s folders and files.)
killall gnome-panel (This forces the panel to close and restart.)
```

Any other ideas how to bring them back? I really need the battery status as i often work unplugged.

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't running already, run 'gnome-panel' from terminal (or logoff and log back in in your gnome session).

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + rightclick (on some pc's <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+rightclick) on the panel where you want the icons and add the Indicator Applet Complete.

That should do it.